# How to use the `onfail` option properly in ffmpeg command?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a command, which takes the input and generates 2 outputs. 1st is encode the video, 2nd is burn the subtitles in the video(if the input has subtitles in it). P.S My input video is live and chunked as 60 min blocks.

```
ffmpeg -i input-file.ts -c:v libx264 -c:a libfdk_aac encoded-video.ts \
          -vf subtitles=input.ts burnt-video.ts -v verbose
```

I always need the encoded-video.ts file. Input video won't have the subtitles always.

I want to ignore the second output stream burnt-video.ts file if it fails(it is supposed to fail if the input video doesn't have subtitles in it).

How to use that [onfail:ignore] option to achieve this? I have seen some answers earlier related to onfail option, but they are dealing with streaming only.

Please someone help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not possible. Filter init will fail if no subtitle track is found and command will abort. onfail is specific to the tee muxer and not relevant here.

Comment: @Gyan okay, what if I have some other stream to encode instead of subtitle burning. There is one similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60188687/how-to-ignore-the-other-output-streams-if-failed-in-ffmpeg). That question is also requesting the usage of option onfail. That would help me a bit.